# How add deleted event on Umbraco Forms admin side and It show only two work flows (Submit and OnApproved)

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-forms

I am unable to find deleted event or workflow in umbraco , umbraco forms. Basically I want to write some custom code and remove record on deleted event.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is not a workflow for that. You have [this custom workflow](https://github.com/mindrevolution/Contour-Delete-Record-Workflow/blame/master/DeleteWorkflow.cs) or you should create an event handler that listen the `RecordDeleting` or `RecordDeleted` events:

```
Umbraco.Forms.Data.Storage.RecordStorage.RecordDeleting += RecordStorage_RecordDeleting;

Umbraco.Forms.Web.Services.RecordService.RecordDeleted += RecordService_RecordDeleted;

private void RecordService_RecordDeleted(object sender, Umbraco.Forms.Core.RecordEventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
}

 private void RecordStorage_RecordDeleting(object sender, Umbraco.Forms.Core.RecordEventArgs e)
 {
    //your code here
 }
```